# Product CSS grid / list view in homefeatured module

Tags: html, css, prestashop-1.6

I have a custom module that is supposed to display the home featured products on a custom dynamic cms page. So far, so good, the page is rendered, the products are in place but..

The link is:
https://florariata.ro/344-florarie-online-Prahova-Ploiesti.html

As you can see, the css is `class="product_list grid row homefeatured tab-pane"` but in the same time, the display used is the one from the list vie not from the grid.. By this way, the list is messed up and the products are rendered like they are now..
Basically, the description and name of product are doubled because both classes are displayed (`grid-desc` and `list-desc`)

Could someone explain what is wrong? I cleared the cache in all the possible ways known but still without success..

Could someone point me to the right way?